# Is it possible to store Zimbra users in an external LDAP server?

Tags: ldap, zimbra

Our system is using a LDAP server (*OUD*) and we're bringing Zimbra to the system. However, Zimbra use its default LDAP server (*OpenLDAP*). That's is paintul with 2 LDAP servers which store same user information.

**Is there any way that Zimbra store its users in an *external* LDAP server?**

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Nope, zimbra needs his own internal LDAP server. Zimbra LDAP server stores user accounts, Class of Services, global settings and servers configuration.

The best practice is to manage user accounts in an external LDAP server (OpenLdap, Active Directory...) and then sync data beetwen external LDAP and Zimbra internal LDAP. There are many scripts on the Internet you'll find to do that.

You can either configure "Delegated Auth", zimbra will validate user auth against you external LDAP server and not internal LDAP (unless you activate the fallback). The point is to manage user passwords in your external LDAP server, so users won't be confused.